# Apache: How to add Expires headers to files without mod_expires installed

Tags: php, apache, mod-expires

I'm on a shared host running Apache. Apparently mod_expires is not installed.
Is there another way to add expires headers to css-files, images etc. on that environment?

Comment: What directives do you want to emulate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `.htaccess` (if that's an option) you can use a [`<FilesMatch>` block](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#filesmatch) with [`Header` directives](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_headers.html#header). This requires `mod_headers`, though, and I'm pretty sure that you *can't* specify a "rolling" expiration date (i.e., "one year from now"). Therefore, you'll need to edit this setting, say, once a year<sup>1</sup>.

Also, did you see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3626036/add-expires-header-without-mod-expires)?

---

<sup>1)</sup> Apparently you should refrain from setting the `Expires` to more than a year into the future: *"Do not set it [the `Expires` header] to more than one year in the future, as that violates the RFC guidelines."* (source: [Optimize caching](http://code.google.com/speed/page-speed/docs/caching.html))

Comment: That worked. Thanks a lot. I don't mind editing it once a year.

Comment: @Hedge Great, it's an easy fix, after all.

Answer (score 2):

You can use PHP to embed expiration headers,
is not efficient as apache mod_expires,
but as least it still able served for primed cache

> Using a far future Expires header affects page views only after a user has
>   already visited your site. It has no effect on the number of HTTP requests when
>   a user visits your site for the first time and the browser's cache is empty.
>   Therefore the impact of this performance improvement depends on how often users
>   hit your pages with a primed cache. (A "primed cache" already contains all of
>   the components in the page.) We measured this at Yahoo!  and found the number
>   of page views with a primed cache is 75-85%. By using a far future Expires
>   header, you increase the number of components that are cached by the browser
>   and re-used on subsequent page views without sending a single byte over the
>   user's Internet connection.

source: http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#expires

Answer (score 2):

Just send the [Header](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields) yourself using [header()](http://php.net/header)

```
header("Expires: Thu, 01 Dec 1994 16:00:00 GMT", true);
```

Edit:
Didnt see, that images, ... are also mentioned. This only works for php files or anything you pass-through php, which in most cases is not a really good idea.